# No devices in sound settings

Tags: sound, system

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. As you can see in the screenshot, there are no devices shown in Sound settings, all fields are empty.

[image: sound settings]

Here is the output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: J40 [Jabra Evolve2 40], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Au [ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 USB Au], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: is package  `linux-firmware` on your system?